# Mahlo operation, consistency border

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

Can a (relatively consistent) cardinal notion be given so that its usual Mahlo operation
is (probably at least) **not** consistent?

Comment: What is "usual Mahlo operation"?

Comment: Mahlo operation of a cardinal property is making those cardinals below some cardinal stationary.I suspect that no such cardinal as asked in my OQ is possible.

Comment: As you know , a Mahlo cardinal has a stationary subset of regular cardinals.  I dk what you are asking. Are you asking about some non-obvious property $P$ such that $\{x<k:P(x)\}$  cannot be stationary in $k$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just replace "regular" with something else so that what you say holds. But the property $P$ may be even obvious but should be a cardinal notion. I think this cannot be done at all.

Comment: The cardinal property is because otherwise countable in uncountable cofinality will do.

Answer (score 1):

Sure - "is a successor ordinal." For any *(fine, uncountable)* infinite cardinal $\kappa$, the set of limit cardinals below $\kappa$ is a club which avoids the set of successor ordinals.

I suspect, though, that this isn't really what you want. So in the opposite direction, let me observe:

> There is no known, currently-considered-consistent [large cardinal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal) whose Mahlo version is known to be (or even suspected to be) inconsistent.

This is an awkward thing to claim since it's inherently hard (if not impossible) to justify, but it is to the best of my knowledge true.